# jquery ui tabs support for the browers back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, back-button

I have a jquery driven web application and a particular page on the site, I use the jquery ui tab control - http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

This enables me to have a page where content separated by tabs.

This works well without issue.

I now need to add support for the browsers back button - so if I have 4 tabs - A, B, C, D and currently on tab C. When I press the back button of the browser, I would like to return to tab B and press it again, return to tab A. How can I integrate this in to the jquery ui tabs?

Secondly, I when the browsers back button is pressed, along with moving to the previous tab, I would like for the page NOT to refresh if possible. So that the movement for the user seemless and close to instant. How possible is this?

Comment: wow... I think you asked for three separate things there.  Back button support will allow someone to be on tab A, go to tab C, click back and end up on tab A again (not B).  Also, clicking the back button will always cause the page to reload.  It's a  very fast load because most all of it is in the cache, but it still has to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use the jQuery BBQ plugin by Ben - http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Similar to your requirement is the demo that Ben provides at http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-basic/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You're confusing the browser back button's role. It is meant go back in browsing history, not to cycle thru your tabs. You need to add a prev/next link on you page to cycle thru your tabs.

Comment: The tabs become "browsing history" when employed the way they are employed. When we sit most users down they expect that the back button will take them to the last visual screen they saw. They don't care that that was an entirely new page or just a tab.

Comment: @AgileJedi: That's an implementation detail, not necessarily the standard behavior.